# Mysql - Opitmizing a range query with group by

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.6

I have a table with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `saleId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `orderId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shopId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fulfillableQuantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fulfillmentStatus` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grams` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `productExists` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `variantId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requiresShipping` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taxable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` text,
  `totalDiscounts` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `variantTitle` text,
  `cogs` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerEmail` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `processedAt` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shippingCost` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `rowStatus` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processedAtNano` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdated` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`saleId`),
  KEY `i_shopId_nano` (`shopId`,`processedAtNano`),
  KEY `i_sales_orderid` (`orderId`),
  KEY `i_sales_variantid` (`variantId`),
  KEY `date_and_product_index` (`shopId`,`processedAtNano`,`productId`,`rowStatus`),
  KEY `i_sales_custemail` (`customerEmail`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `i_sales_test_index` (`shopId`,`processedAtNano`,`rowStatus`,`customerEmail`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT
    get_total_freq(MAX(s.processedAtNano),
        MIN(s.processedAtNano),
        count(s.customerEmail)) AS a
FROM
    sales AS s
WHERE
    s.shopId = 'p2k-c5k-o100k'
    AND s.processedAtNano < 1525132799999
    AND s.customerEmail IS NOT NULL
    AND s.customerEmail != ''
    AND s.rowStatus = 'ok'
GROUP BY
    s.customerEmail
HAVING
    count(s.customerEmail) > 1)
```

but this just **won't use the indexes** and would start `using where` and `filesort`

below is the explain for this query:

```
1|"SIMPLE"|"s"|"ref"|"i_shopId_nano,date_and_product_index,i_sales_test_index"|"i_shopId_nano"|"103"|"const"|277686|"Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"|
```

I have experimented with all logical permutations of indexes that I can think of but still, the **query time is 11sec, while without the group by its 630ms**

definition of `get_total_freq`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_total_freq`(max BIGINT, min BIGINT, no_of_orders INT) RETURNS double
begin
    declare value double;
    set value = DATEDIFF( from_unixtime(floor(max/1000)), 
from_unixtime(floor(min/1000)) )/ (no_of_orders-1);
    RETURN value;
end
```

**UPDATE**

Solution I ended up using thanks to both `Rick James` and `jonggu` as it was a mix of both

The final index that I created

```
"i_sales_stack" => "shopId,rowStatus,customerEmail,processedAtNano"
```

And the final query I'm using

```
SELECT
    avg(b.total_freq)
FROM
    sales AS s, (
        SELECT
            saleId,
            get_total_reorder_freq (MAX(a.processedAtNano),
                MIN(a.processedAtNano),
                count(a.customerEmail)) AS total_freq
        FROM
            sales AS a
        WHERE
            a.shopId = 'p2k-c5k-o100k'
            AND a.rowStatus = 'ok'
        GROUP BY
            a.customerEmail
        HAVING
            count(a.customerEmail) > 1) AS b
    WHERE
        s.saleId = b.saleId
        AND s.processedAtNano < 1531440000000
        AND s.customerEmail != ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  WHERE s.shopId = 'p2k-c5k-o100k'
    AND s.processedAtNano < 1525132799999
    AND s.customerEmail IS NOT NULL   -- remove
    AND s.customerEmail != ''
    AND s.rowStatus = 'ok'
```

First, let's look at the two tests for `customerEmail`.  `NULL` makes any test fail, so `customerEmail != ''` already covers the `IS NOT NULL` test.

To build the optimal index, start with `=` tests.

```
INDEX(shopId, rowStatus,   -- first, in either order
      customerEmail,       -- not sure if it can get pat this
      processedAtNano)     -- range last
```

The `GROUP BY` cannot be subsumed by any `INDEX` because no index can effectively handle the entire `WHERE`.  Hence the filesort is inevitable.

It does not make sense to `GROUP BY customerEmail` without having that column in the `SELECT`.

What is `get_total_freq()`?

Meanwhile `i_shopId_nano` is unnecessary because of `i_sales_test_index`.

The difference between `count(s.customerEmail)` and `COUNT(*)` is that the former tests for `NULL`.  But you have excluded such.

Comment: Have added `GROUP By customerEmail` cause the we have to get the `get_total_freq` by every customer who has purchased before `1525132799999`. I have read that the **index are always used if the follow the order of where clause**, is this false?

Comment: Have added the definition of `get_total_freq` in the question

Comment: @AnkitLadhania - Rearranging the order of tests in `WHERE` has no impact on the Optimization.  Rearranging the order of columns in an `INDEX` _may_ have a serious impact.

Comment: @AnkitLadhania - And...  An index is used _if_ the Optimizer decides that it would speed up the query.  That decision is based on various things.

Comment: The test is really for "purchases before 15..."  And you are excluding customers who purchased only one item before that date.

Comment: @AnkitLadhania - And you are failing to identify which customer belongs to which get_total_freq output.  What do you do with the resultset?

Comment: ,this metric is called reorder frequency which means, the average number of days in which people reorder, so for one customer having n orders it would be `(2nd order time - 1st order time)/2` + `(3rd order time - 2nd order time) /2` and so on. which complies to `(nth order time - 1st order time)/n-1`. I hope this makes sense. Let me know if you have a better way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Change index like.

KEY `i_sales_test_index` (`shopId`,`rowStatus`,`customerEmail`)

```
SELECT
    1 AS sortKey,
    avg(avgs.a) AS reorder_freq
FROM (
    SELECT
        b.total_freq AS a
    FROM
        sales AS s, (
            SELECT
                saleId,
                get_total_freq (MAX(a.processedAtNano),
                    MIN(a.processedAtNano),
                    count(a.customerEmail)) AS total_freq
            FROM
                sales AS a
            WHERE
                a.shopId = 'p2k-c5k-o100k'
                AND a.rowStatus = 'ok'
            GROUP BY
                a.customerEmail
            HAVING
                count(a.customerEmail) > 1) AS b
        WHERE
            s.saleId = b.saleId
            AND s.processedAtNano < 1525132799999
            AND s.customerEmail IS NOT NULL
            AND s.customerEmail != '') AS avgs
```

Comment: Can you please explain your logic behind this optimization?

Comment: @AnkitLadhania My query is doing self join. Because index doesn't apply after range search.

Comment: Thanks your solution helped, so just for my understanding, MySQL doesn't use index after range queries?

Comment: @AnkitLadhania Yes. MySQL doesn't use index after range condition for composite index

Comment: it did speed up the query from previous one but it was not what I ended up using, please see the index that Rick James suggested that is more optimized